# SQL Server : generating xml with security header for soap web service

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, soap

I have a task to create a procedure in SQL Server that can generate XML and communicate with a SOAP web service.

This is how the XML should look:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
    <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-10788FB36F6242F7FE151731009896412">
        <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">5/0ZUluzscbIlR5RcT6Rgg==</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2018-01-30T11:01:38.963Z</wsu:Created>
   </wsse:UsernameToken>
   </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetTransportMethods>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:Dealer_code>?</tem:Dealer_code>
      </tem:GetTransportMethods>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is there any possible way to regenerate this in SQL Server? Especially generate `UsernameToken`, `Nonce` and `Created`? Thanks

Comment: Do you know, if the namespace declarations must be exactly like in your example or might all of them live in the first-level node `<soapenv:Envelope>`? The problem with the native SQL-Server's XML is, that `xmlns:soapenv` is declared in first-level, while `wsse` and `wsu` are declared in `<wsse:Security>`. Semantically this was not necessary...

Comment: i'm not sure. This xml is just request generated by SoapUI and i need to replicate it with sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should create exactly the same XML as you posted above, with one difference: The places where the namespaces are declared. My code will place all declarations within the first-level node `<soapenv:Envelope>`. This is - semantically - the same as yours. But very strict validators might bark...

If you are forced to create it exactly as above you must use tricks on string level using `REPLACE()`, `STUFF()` and similar functions...

One word about ordering: The elements order within an XML is an implicit part of the document. **But the order of attributes may be different!** This is by definition!

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS soapenv
                  ,'http://tempuri.org/' AS tem
                  ,'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' AS wsse
                  ,'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd' AS wsu)

SELECT 1 AS [soapenv:Header/wsse:Security/@soapenv:mustUnderstand]
      ,'UsernameToken-10788FB36F6242F7FE151731009896412' AS [soapenv:Header/wsse:Security/wsse:UsernameToken/@wsu:Id]
      ,'username' AS [soapenv:Header/wsse:Security/wsse:UsernameToken/wsse:Username]
      ,'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText' AS [soapenv:Header/wsse:Security/wsse:UsernameToken/wsse:Password/@Type]
      ,'password' AS [soapenv:Header/wsse:Security/wsse:UsernameToken/wsse:Password]
      ,'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary' AS [soapenv:Header/wsse:Security/wsse:UsernameToken/wsse:Nonce/@EncodingType]
      ,'5/0ZUluzscbIlR5RcT6Rgg==' AS [soapenv:Header/wsse:Security/wsse:UsernameToken/wsse:Nonce]
      ,'2018-01-30T11:01:38.963Z' AS [soapenv:Header/wsse:Security/wsse:UsernameToken/wsu:Created]
      ,'?' AS [soapenv:Body/tem:GetTransportMethods/tem:Dealer_code]
FOR XML PATH('soapenv:Envelope')
```

The result

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
                  xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
                  xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" 
                  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
      <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-10788FB36F6242F7FE151731009896412">
        <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">5/0ZUluzscbIlR5RcT6Rgg==</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2018-01-30T11:01:38.963Z</wsu:Created>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <tem:GetTransportMethods>
      <tem:Dealer_code>?</tem:Dealer_code>
    </tem:GetTransportMethods>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Yes, but i need to generate different UsernameToken, Nonce and Created. Is it even possible with sql server ?

Comment: @MatejRandík You can place any data within your XML. Just set whatever you want between the comma and the `AS`: e.g. change `'password' AS [soapenv:...` to `'blah' AS [soapenv:...`

Comment: The think is that when i wan't access to web service i need new unique token and nonce every time.

Comment: @MatejRandík You question is only about *generating-xml-with-security-header* The values you have to place inside (especially the `base64` encoded binary within `<wsse:Nonce>`) must be provided by yourself. I do not get, what you really want to get answered. My suggestion: It seems to me, that this question is answered. If you think so too, please close it (by accepting my answer) and start a new question (with a link to this one). Other people with more knowledge on SOAP security will rush in for help soon...